# Algorithm to traverse graph with certain dependency/constraint

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, traversal

So I am building a operations pipeline that allows user to apply certain Data operations on dataframes.
The operations are such that they may have "one-input-->two-outputs" or "one-input-->one-output" or "two-inputs-->one-output".

[image]

I need to traverse the graph from the starting points labelled as [S1, S2, S3, S4] and reach the end points
The important thing to note is that in order to execute operation2, we need to have operation1 and operation5 already executed. similarly to execute operation7, operations 3 and 6 need to be already executed.

Note that this is simpler than a directed acyclic graph as we have clear start and end points and the flow is unidirectional [left-->right in the image]

It is known which operations are the starting points marked as S1,s2,s3,s4. I need to execute all operations and reach the terminal points. I just the need the pseudocode.

Comment: if i start from S1 i can only execute till operation1 since the next operation2 requires the output of operation5 as well

Comment: Is this a topological sort problem? Will it be the ideal solution if first find all the end points and then apply topological sort for all the end points?

Comment: 'Note that this is simpler than a directed acyclic graph as we have clear start and end points and the flow is unidirectional' - I honestly do not see the slightest difference to a DAG model, what am I missing?

Comment: My initial reaction to reading your question was “this looks like topological sorting.” You mentioned topological sort in the comments. Is there any reason topological sort won’t work here?

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be some kind of task scheduling problem,  It is impossible to say exactly what kind or offer any concrete suggestion because the question is missing many important details.

1. How long does each task take.  Does each task take the same time
   on every processor.  ( If task take no time, then no waiting is
   reuired and the problem becomes trivial )
2. How many processors are available.  ( Can tasks be completed in parrallel, or one by one, or only a small number in parallels. )
3. What do you want to optimize for?  Total time to complete all tasks.  Minimize number of processors.  Something else.
4. What is the output you want to see.

There is a vast literature on task scheduling problems.  A reasonable starting point would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)

Since you have almost no information about the problem the best you can acieve is to find a feasible execution order, assuming no parralel task execution.

1. Add a starting node, with links to each of the s nodes.

[image]

2. Do a breadth first search of the tree, recording the nodes as they are visited.

Comment: There is no parallel processing here

Comment: OK. Edit your question to specify this important constraint - only one process can execute at a time.  You will also need to specify how long each process requires to execute.

Comment: It is not known how long it will take. I don't think it's even relevant. I just need to find the correct execution order

Comment: The "right" execution order depends on the details: timing, processor count, etc, etc.  If you really do not know how long your tasks take to execute, then your problem cannot be optimized.

Comment: Perhaps all you want is a feasible order of execution?  If that is it, then the problem is trivial.  Simply do a breadth first search through the graph.  Since you have multiple starting points, you will need to add an extra starting node with a link to each of the real starting nodes.

Comment: BFS doesn't take into account the inter dependencies, for instance operation7 requires the output of operation3 and operation6.

Comment: Is a feasible order of execution all that you want?  You understand that there will be multiple feasible orders, all "correct"?  If that is all, then I can detail haw to use BFS to produce one of the feasible orders.  Otherwise, you will need to provide more information.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want. Order of operations is important. 
I figured out a solution where I do a BFS traversal using a Queue and if an operation is encountered that is not "ready" for execution yet (i.e. the operations that it is dependent on have NOT been executed yet), I just put it back to the queue without visiting it.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you could handle this problem, I've posted a JavaScript snuppet below which prints out the order of operations. The first part is representing the graph, for example:

```js
[
  [[inputs], [outputs]]  // where the index is the operation #
]
```

The next step would be determining the order of operations and how you want the system to execute these operations. I came up with the following sequence based on the diagram:

```
0, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

Which makes sense since step #2 for example cannot complete until step #5 is finished so on and so forth. From this we can come up with a couple rules for our algorithm:

1. Traverse the graph in ascending order
2. An operation can be executed and marked complete if:
3. All of the inputs are also marked as complete
4. The inputs are `null` indicating the first operation of a sequence
5. If the inputs are not complete backtrack operations until we hit `null`
6. Once complete traverse all output operations until we hit `null`

One issue with this approach is the above graph is disjointed and so we do need to run the traverse function for each `s1`, `s2`, `s3`, `s4`

```js
// The index numbers are just for illustration
const operationsGraph = {
  0: [null, [1]],
  1: [[0], [2]],
  2: [[1, 5], [3]],
  3: [[2], [4, 7]],
  4: [[3], null],
  5: [null, [2]],
  6: [null, [7]],
  7: [[3, 6], [8]],
  8: [[7], null],
  9: [null, [10]],
  10: [[9], null],
};

// Convert the graph to an array
const operation = Object.values(operationsGraph);

// Create an array to keep track of the completed operations
const completed = Array(operation.length).fill(false);

/**
 * The algorithm works as follows:
 *
 *  1. move along path until (2 inputs needed)
 *  2. backtrack until base case
 *  3. continue in lowest completed order
 *
 *   [complete] <--- [current] ----> [complete]
 */

function traverse(pointer) {
  // if this step has been completed return
  if (completed[pointer]) return true;
  // extract the prev and next operations
  const prev = operation[pointer][0];
  const next = operation[pointer][1];
  // backtrack each previous operation
  prev?.forEach((op) => traverse(op));
  // if the previous step is complete and this operation
  // has been completed then mark as completed and print
  if (isComplete(prev) && completed[pointer] === false) {
    // update the completed flag
    completed[pointer] = true;
    // run the operation here
    console.log('running: ', pointer);
  }
  // iterate the next steps in the sequence
  next?.forEach((op) => traverse(op));
}

// helper function to check if a step is complete
function isComplete(step) {
  if (step === null) return true;
  return step.every((i) => completed[i]);
}

// run each of the sequences
function main() {
  const s1 = traverse(0);
  const s2 = traverse(5);
  const s3 = traverse(6);
  const s4 = traverse(9);
}

main()
```